# How to return multiple unique values with multipe criteria (excel geo-data)?

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, indexing, matching

I'm working with a very large geo-dataset that looks like this:

```
-        NYC   Boston   LA   Dallas   Rome
NYC      -       4       2     9       21
Boston    4      -       11    8       6 
LA        2      11      -     1       18
Dallas    9      8       1     -       7
Rome      21     6       18    7       -
```

I'm trying to fetch all relevant values across several criteria horizontally, for example:

```
Criteria:    >0     >0     >3       >3       >3
Criteria:    <3     <3     <10      <10      <10
NYC          LA      -     Boston   Dallas    -
Boston        -      -     NYC      Dallas   Rome
etc...
```

I've been trying different formulas using (index, small, rows), but just can't seem to make it work. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work with a formula but you will have to make some very specific formatting changes to your layout. Per the supplied image,

- B2, C3, D4, E5, F6 are zeroes, not hyphens.
- B2:F6 have a custom number format of `_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);[Color9]_(* "-"_);_(@_)`.
- I1:M1 have values of 0, 0, 3, 3, 3 and a custom number format of `>0`.
- I2:M2 have values of 3, 3, 10, 10, 10 and a custom number format of `<0`.
- I3:M7 have a custom number format of `_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);[Color9]_(* "-"_);_(@_)`.

Put this formula in I3 then drag right and down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$F$1, AGGREGATE(15, 7, COLUMN($A:$F)/((INDEX($A:$F, MATCH($H3, $A:$A, 0), 0)>I$1)*(INDEX($A:$F, MATCH($H3, $A:$A, 0), 0)<I$2)*(INDEX($A:$F, MATCH($H3, $A:$A, 0), 0)<>0)), COUNTIFS($I$1:I$1, I$1, $I$2:I$2, I$2))), 0)
```

[image]